# Does a MacBook connected to a PD charger charge the iPhone with power from adapter or battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I have an M1Pro Macbook Pro, and there is only one power outlet where I usually work. I have a 65W PD charger and I always use it to charge my Macbook. I know that my Macbook works with only the power the charger supplies and there won't be much wear-and-tear to the battery. Now I wish to charge my iPhone by connecting it to the Macbook. I want to know if the charger can supply sufficient power, which power supply will the Macbook use: battery or charger, and will it cause extra Macbook battery wear-and-tear?

Comment: Using the same charger to regulate “wear and tear” on the battery is fiction.  Your battery functions due to an ongoing  chemical reaction.   So whether brand new Apple (made and sourced in China) or some bargain basement Chinese- ium, it’s going to have that chemical reaction occur even if sitting on a shelf